# What's the influence of Log?

Tags: android, audio, decode, encode

```
private static byte[] encodedData = new byte[20];
private static Speex speex = Speex.getInstance();
public static byte[] raw2spx(short[] audioData) {
    //Log.e("abc", "length:" + audioData.length);
    speex.encode(audioData, encodedData, audioData.length);
    return encodedData;
}
```

I wrote a function like this, but what makes it strange is that if I don't comment the function of `Log.e()`, the app can run well. But if I comment, the logcat shows me an `ArrayIndexOutBounds` Exception. Why?

Comment: try this. if(audioData !=null) Log.e("abc", "length:" + audioData.length); else Log.e("audioData is Null");

Comment: It will be clearer to post the stack trace also.

Comment: Try: `public static byte[] raw2spx(short[] audioData) throws Exception { ..other code.. }`. It's untested but _might_ allow you to comment the `log.e` code. Also do you have a link to the Speex API documentation? I'd expect the encoder to take 32bit `float` data not 16bit `short` but I'll check the manual if you show a link.

Comment: Is this the [**Speex Encoder**](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)? I see explained :  _"This class encodes the given PCM 16bit samples into Speex packets."_ so I guess it does accept 16bit values (short)...